# Cross product problem

Tags: determinant, vector-analysis, cross-product

someone could show me the error in the cross products?

For $U=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$, $V=x'\hat{i}+y'\hat{j}+z'\hat{k}$ and $((.))$=modulus, we have

$$U \times V=((U))((V))sin(U,V).n = \begin{vmatrix} \hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ x & y & z \\ x' & y' & z' \end{vmatrix} $$

(1) $U=2\hat{i}$, $V=160(-\hat{j})$ and $sin(2\hat{i},-160\hat{j})=1$
$$U\times V=2\hat{i} \times (-160)\hat{j}=((2\hat{i}))((-160\hat{j})).(\hat{i} \times \hat{j})=2.160.\hat{k}=320\hat{k}$$

(2) $2\hat{i} \times (-160)\hat{j}=\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k}\\
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -160 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=-320\hat{k}$

They just don't match..

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector $\vec n$ has to be not just perpendicular, but in the direction specified by the right-hand rule.  So it is $-\vec k$, not $\vec k$